# App Center won't show installed programms // won't install new ones

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

Since yesterday the App Center won't work properly anymore.

Doesn't show installed programms anymore:

[image: Doesn't show installed programms anymore]

Won't download nor install new ones:

[image]

Already tried:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> > sudo reboot
>
> sudo apt purge appcenter
>
> > sudo apt-get install appcenter
> >
> > > sudo apt-get update
> > >
> > > > sudo reboot

nothing worked... any ideas?

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? If so could you please mark one of the answers below? And if you resolved it another way, please post that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to force update the app stream by using

```
sudo appstreamcli refresh-cache --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you try to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt update
```

Then start AppCenter again.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. didn't work either. i did a reinstall, works like a charm now

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be related to what many of us experienced recently. The elementary team pushed out a fix that might be what you're looking for. Apparently there was an issue with the PackageKit library.

https://medium.com/elementaryos/important-update-released-501c9d9f28b

In the terminal...

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install packagekit
```